# Combine sp result in select as column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute sp as sub query and treat result set of sp as column of outer query . Some thing like this

`Select U.FirstName , (exec SomeSP ) as columnFromSP from User U`

Is this possible i searched alot but found nothing on google.

**Update**

I cannot use #temp table because i am trying to do without #temp table

Comment: You cannot do it this way. You will have to either change the SP or store the result into a temp table and join with your user table

Comment: You could convert your SomeSP to be a table valued function and then you can do this without a temp table.

Comment: Sean can you add any example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to convert your USP to a table value UDF, you will be use the UDF in your FROM statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SomeUDF
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @param varchar(1000)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

    SELECT @param as Value
)
GO

SELECT 
    a.Value,
    'B' as Value2 
FROM dbo.SomeUDF('ABC') a
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, but you can work around it

- Create a temp table & insert the results of the procedure into
  it
- Now join the User table with the temporary table and select the
  columns you want from both tables

This assumes however, you have a joinable expression returned from the stored proc (one that you can match to a field in the user table).  If the stored procedure on returns a single row, use a condition of 1=1 or something similar

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Declare a temp table and column(for eg you have only 1 column)
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
   FirstName VARCHAR(50)       
)

-- The results after execution will be inserted to this table
INSERT INTO #TEMP
Exec SomeSP 'Params'

-- Select records from both tables in all combinations
SELECT U.FirstName , COL1 as columnFromSP 
from User U
CROSS JOIN #TEMP
```

Comment: I have modified the result. You can try this @Ancient